# How do I make my Electron app the default for opening files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am making an electron app with which the user can edit .txt files. I was wondering if it was possible to make the app the default app to open .txt files with... do I add something to the packge.json? How do I handle the file? I know this question is sort of broad but I can not find anything in the docs so if I could be pointed in the right direction that would be great.

Other info:

Packaging: packaging with electron builder

Node: v12.14.1

npm: 6.14.1

Electron: 9.0.4

Comment: default app is handled by the OS, not the app, though in windows your app can set it through registry, not sure with linux and mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) config, specifically [fileAssociations](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#PlatformSpecificBuildOptions-fileAssociations).

Nutshell:

`fileAssociations` allows setting `ext`, which you'd set to `txt` IIRC. You can also provide a descriptive `name`, give it icons, and several platform-specific options.

---

Unrelated, but this took about a minute of searching. For reference:

1. Googled for "electron app make default for opening a type of files"
2. Found an Electron issue that looked promising.
3. Scrolled to a reference to electron-builder, which fit your question nicely.
4. Made clicky on the links, made sure it was reasonable.
5. Didn't test because on wrong laptop, but seems legit.

Comment: hmm.. ok thanks i have no idea why I could't find anything, but how do you handle the file?

Comment: Since this is the first Google result now. You'll also need to handle the event inside your app. See the `app` docs starting here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-file-macos

Comment: On Windows, you have to parse process.argv (in the main process) to get the filepath.
On linux anybody knows maybe?