# Electron: Windows alternative for app.on 'open-file'

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, electron-builder

I am building an Electron app for editing .txt files on a windows computer. I have used electron builders `fileAssociations` to open .txt files however I cannot get the path of the file. When I looked in the Electron docs I found [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app?q=ready#event-open-file-macos) which is exactly what I want except it is mac-only... is there a way to get the same functionality on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

As Lucas Roland mentioned, you have to parse `process.argv` to get the filepath

```
if (process.argv.length >= 2) { // or electron.remote.process.argv
    let filePath = process.argv[1];
    //open, read, handle file
}
```

Comment: When the app is is packaged, `process.argv` looks different than in development. Use `const argsArray = process.argv.slice(app.isPackaged ? 1 : 2);` to handle both cases, and then in this case `const filePath = argsArray[0];`

Answer (score 0):

> On Windows, you have to parse process.argv (in the main process) to
> get the filepath.

from https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#event-open-file-macos

Comment: Could you explain how to do this a little more thouroughly?

Comment: i think the authors problem is not parsing the process.argv, the problem is to knwo when he should parse the process.argv. i cant find an event for this too

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to use `process.argv` in the main process to read the file path. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425619/3070768), you can use the `fs` package to open, read & write files. There are a few more ways described to do the same thing.

Also, the following snippet from [this blog post](https://blog.theodo.com/2015/12/link-files-to-application-in-windows/) might be helpful.

> How to configure your app to open linked files in Windows
>
> On Windows, you have to parse process.argv to get the file path.
> Then, you can use the IPC module to handle messages from the renderer process (web page) and retrieve a datastore from a file. This is how we did it:
>
> In the main process:

```js
var ipc = require('ipc');
var fs = require('fs');

// read the file and send data to the render process
ipc.on('get-file-data', function(event) {
  var data = null;
  if (process.platform == 'win32' && process.argv.length >= 2) {
    var openFilePath = process.argv[1];
    data = fs.readFileSync(openFilePath, 'utf-8');
  }
  event.returnValue = data;
});
```

I am not very well versed with `electron`, else I would have tried to give you a better answer, but this is what I could find with my understanding about it. I hope this helps!

Comment: The blog post link above might also answer your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62420427/3070768)

Answer (score 0):

For windows, parsing process.argv on app ready worked for me. So in the main process somewhere:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
const devEnv = /electron/.test(process.argv[0]);

app.on('ready', () => {
   if (process.platform.startsWith('win') && !devEnv && process.argv.length >= 2) {
      const filePath = process.argv[1];

      // In my app, I initialise a new window here and send filePath through 
      // to the renderer process so it can be read and displayed.

   } else {

      // Create whatever your default window is (in my case, an empty document)      

   }
});
```

On windows, this event is fired every time you open a new file even if another file is already open in the application.

Remember also that during development, we launch the application with `electron .` or `electron . --debug` or something similar. Because of this, I also test whether the first argument is `electron` and skip over file opening logic in this case (the case that `devEnv` evaluates to 'true').

Comment: To handle the difference between development and production, you can use `const argsArray = process.argv.slice(app.isPackaged ? 1 : 2);` , and then in this case `const filePath = argsArray[0];`, and you can do this outside of the `'ready'` event if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative that I have found for this problem is using `second-instance` event on the `app` module with `process.argv`.

When a user clicks a file associated with your app, on Windows (yeah! I only tried it on Windows), it will try to open a new instance of the app with the path of the related file inside `process.argv`. If you are not using multiple instances of the app, then you should prevent the app from opening multiple instances of the app and try to fetch the data (mainly the `process.argv`) to the main instance using the `second-instance` event from the `app` module.

First, you should get the singleInstanceLock from `app.requestSingleInstanceLock()` to make the current instance the only instance of the app. This will return a boolean. If it returns false, this means that another instance has the singleInstanceLock. Then you should close that instance using `app.quit()`.

```js
// Behaviour on second instance for parent process
const gotSingleInstanceLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!gotSingleInstanceLock) app.quit(); // Quits the app if app.requestSingleInstanceLock() returns false.
```

If the boolean is true, then this means the current app session is the main session of the app.
Then we should use the `second-instance` event of the `app` module to detect second instances from that point onwards. If another instance emerges, it will be closed, but `second-instance` event will be fired with the relevant arguments needed to identify what opened that instance to the `process.argv`. The second parameter of the callback added to the `second-instance` event can be used to get those arguments sent to that instance. From that point onwards, you can filter the strings inside the `process.argv` and get the relevant path of the file that opened the other instance.

```js
// Behaviour on the second instance for the parent process
const gotSingleInstanceLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!gotSingleInstanceLock) app.quit();
else {
  app.on('second-instance', (_, argv) => {
    //User requested a second instance of the app.
    //argv has the process.argv arguments of the second instance.
    if (app.hasSingleInstanceLock()) {
      if (mainWindow?.isMinimized()) mainWindow?.restore();
      mainWindow?.focus();
      process.argv = argv; // I tried to add the argv from the second instance to my main instance. 
    }
  });
}
```

Please keep in mind that arguments in `process.argv` will be added differently when the app is packaged. Therefore, you should loop through the arguments and check whether an argument is a path in the system using the `stat()` function in the `fs` module and if it has the `.txt` extension at the end using the `path.extname()`

I found this method the hard way, so I hope that anyone with this problem wouldn't have to go through all of that.